# How to solve the following error - An error occurred while sending the digest (undefined method `length' for true:TrueClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redmine-plugins

I have been trying to configure a plugin from the following link - https://www.redmine.org/plugins/digest

and when i am trying to send a test mail, I am getting the following error. 
undefined method `length' for true:TrueClass

This is the error in log file

```
Looking up projects to process...
Couldn't find all EnabledModules with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["name = 'redmine_digest'"]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
undefined method `length' for true:TrueClass
["/home/administrator/redmine3.1/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/redmine_digest/app/controllers/digest_controller.rb:84:in `digest_send'", "/home/administrator/redmine3.1/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/redmine_digest/app/controllers/digest_controller.rb:129:in `test_email'", "/home/administrator/redmine3.1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'",
```

digest_controller.rb file
if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR < 3
    require 'rdoc/markup/simple_markup'
    require 'rdoc/markup/simple_markup/to_html'
else
    require 'rdoc'
end

class DigestController < ApplicationController
    unloadable

```
layout 'admin'

def show_readme
    filename = 'README.rdoc'
    f = File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../' + filename
    input_string = File.open(f, 'rb').read
    if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR >=3
        h = RDoc::Markup::ToHtml.new
        instructions = h.convert(input_string)
    else
        p = SM::SimpleMarkup.new
        h = SM::ToHtml.new
        instructions = p.convert(input_string, h)
    end
    @readme = { 
        :filename => filename, 
        :content => instructions 
    }
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :template => 'settings/digest_readme.html.erb', :layout => 'admin',
        :locals => { :readme => @readme }}
    end
end

def digest_send(which, options={})
    is_session = @request.nil? && @_request.nil?
    is_session = !is_session
    if not is_session
        puts "setting request"
        @_request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(Rails.env)
    end
    if is_session
    raise_delivery_errors = ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors
    # Force ActionMailer to raise delivery errors so we can catch it
    ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
    end
    begin
        case which
        when "options"
            @test = DigestMailer.digests(options)
            message = l(:notice_digests_sent)
        when "test"
            dbg "User.current: %s" % User.current
            dbg "User.current.mail: %s" % User.current.mail
            @test = DigestMailer.test(User.current)
            message = l(:notice_digest_sent_to, User.current.mail)
        when "all"
            @test = DigestMailer.digests
            message = l(:notice_digests_sent)
        else
            message "No case found for '%s'." % which
        end
        if @test.nil? #or @test.empty?
            message += "<p>%s</p>" % "There was no resulting email."
        else
            message += "<p>%d %s processed.<br />%s</p>" % [
                @test.length, 
                @test.length == 1 ? "project was" : "projects were",
                @test.join("<br />")
            ]
        end
        dbg message
        if is_session
            flash[:notice] = message
        end
    rescue Exception => e
        dbg e.message
        dbg e.backtrace
        if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR >= 3
            logger.error("%s: " % e.message) unless logger.nil?
        else
            logger.error e.message, e.backtrace unless logger.nil?
        end
        flash[:error] = l(:notice_digest_error, e.message) unless session.nil?
        if is_session
            flash[:error] = l(:notice_digest_error, e.message)
        else
            puts "Exception occurred: %s" % e.message
        end
    end
    if is_session
        ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = raise_delivery_errors
        redirect_to :controller => 'settings', :action => 'plugin', :id => 'redmine_digest'
    else
        puts "A session was not found."
    end
end

def send_digest(options={})
    dbg "Preparing to send digest..."
    dbg options.inspect
    digest_send("options", options)
end

def send_all
    dbg "Preparing to send digest for all projects."
    digest_send "all"
end

def test_email
    dbg "Preparing to send test digest."
    digest_send "test"
end

def dbg(message)
    if Setting.plugin_redmine_digest[:debugging_messages]
        puts message
        logger.info(message)
    else
        puts "debugging_messages: %s" % Setting.plugin_redmine_digest[:debugging_messages]
        logger.info("debugging_messages: %s" % Setting.plugin_redmine_digest[:debugging_messages])
    end
end

def self.logger
    if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR >= 3
        logger = Rails.logger
    else
        logger = RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER
    end
    return logger unless logger.nil?
    #ActionController::Base::logger
end
```

end

Comment: It's pretty obvious. You are trying to call method `length` on a boolean instance.

Comment: First of all Thank you for replying, but its a plugin developed by other person, I am not able to figure out where this error is occuring.

Comment: i think its in the following lines has been added in the question

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: @PixelBeaver, I have updated the question.

Comment: @ShravyaShetty Sorry, I had to delete my answer, because it wasn't properly answering it. Calling `to_s` on `@test` would surely remove the error, but it would give you unexpected behavior as well. Because calling `@test.to_s` will either you `"true"` or `"false"`, and wouldn't be able to give you the actual required string.

Comment: Would you please like to show me the controller code?

Comment: @Bilal, i have uploaded the method in controller code, would you like to see the whole controller file ?

Comment: @Bilal, I have uploaded the controller code. please can you look at it and correct me?

Answer (score 0):

Checking for `@test.nil?` isn't enough; you also need to check for its type. Either you can convert it to `String` object by calling `to_s` method on `@test`, or you can check for its class, that either it is string or not like following:

```
if !@test.nil? && @test.is_a? String
  # do your stuff
else

end
```

Comment: Bilal, Thank you for you valueable answer, You mean to say I should convert test object to a String?